# How do you speed up a queryset that uses .distinct()?

Tags: django, performance, postgresql, django-models, postgresql-9.1

I'm looking to speed up a query that needs to use distinct because it has a M2M field it selects on. At this point I'm not sure if my speed issues are related to how I have my DB server configured or if it's related to my queryset.

**My question:** What is the fastest queryset and can I also improve the speed by changing my Postgresql settings?

### Postgresql Server Information

Instance: EC2 m1.xlarge
Postgresql Version: 9.1
Article Records: 240,695
Total Memory: 14980 MB
shared_buffers: 3617MB
effective_cache_size: 8000MB
work_mem: 40MB
checkpoint_segments: 10
maintenance_work_mem: 64MB

### Related Models

```
class AuthorsModelMixin(models.Model):

    authors = models.ManyToManyField('people.Person', blank=True)
    nonstaff_authors = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Non-staff authors', max_length=255, blank=True,
        help_text="Used for the name of the author for non-staff members.")
    byline_title = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, blank=True,
        help_text="Often contains an organization. Title of the person, or " \
                  "entity associated with the byline and a specified person " \
                  "(i.e. Associated Press).")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class TaxonomyModelMixin(models.Model):

    sections = models.ManyToManyField(Section, blank=True)
    tags = TaggableManager(
        blank=True, help_text='A comma-separated list of tags (i.e. ' \
                              'Outdoors, Election, My Great News Topic).')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class PublishModelMixin(models.Model):

    status_choices = (
        ('D', 'Draft'),
        ('P', 'Published'),
        ('T', 'Trash'),
    )

    comment_choices = (
        ('enabled', 'Enabled'),
        ('disabled', 'Disabled'),
    )

    sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site, default=[1])
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, default='P', db_index=True, choices=status_choices,
        help_text='Only published items will appear on the site')
    published = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now, db_index=True,
        help_text='Select the date you want the content to be published.')
    is_premium = models.BooleanField(
        choices=((True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No')),
        verbose_name='Premium Content', default=True)
    comments = models.CharField(
        max_length=30, default='enabled',
        choices=comment_choices, help_text='Enable or disable comments.')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = PublishedManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Article(AuthorsModelMixin, TaxonomyModelMixin, PublishModelMixin):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = SlugModelField(max_length=255)
    lead_photo = models.ForeignKey('media.Photo', blank=True, null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True)
    body = models.TextField()
```

### Querysets I've Tried

#### Queryset 1

Query time: (76 ms)
Pros: Fast and no chance published articles won't be displayed
Cons: If a higher id has an older pub date then the article list will be out of order

```
queryset = Article.objects \
                  .published() \
                  .filter(sections__full_slug__startswith=section.full_slug) \
                  .prefetch_related('lead_photo', 'authors') \
                  .order_by('-id') \
                  .distinct('id')
```

#### Queryset 2

Query time: (76 ms)
Pros: Articles are in order all the time
Cons: If two articles have the same pub date and time, only one will be listed

```
queryset = Article.objects \
                  .published() \
                  .filter(sections__full_slug__startswith=section.full_slug) \
                  .prefetch_related('lead_photo', 'authors') \
                  .order_by('-published') \
                  .distinct('published')
```

#### Queryset 3

Query time: (1007 ms)
Pros: Articles are in order all the time and no chance of articles not being listed
Cons: Much slower!

```
queryset = Article.objects \
                  .published() \
                  .filter(sections__full_slug__startswith=section.full_slug) \
                  .prefetch_related('lead_photo', 'authors') \
                  .order_by('-id', '-published') \
                  .distinct('id')
```

#### Queryset 4

Query time: (4797.85 ms)
Pros: Not much, however not using `DISTINCT ON` means it works on other databases like SQLite for tests
Cons: Much slower!!!

```
queryset = Article.objects \
                  .published() \
                  .filter(sections__full_slug__startswith=section.full_slug) \
                  .prefetch_related('lead_photo', 'authors') \
                  .order_by('-published') \
                  .distinct()
```

Comment: Show your models please. Btw I am not sure, but "prefetch_related" maybe follows ForeignKey(Field) relations to a depth of 5. As I said, not sure wheter this is the case here.

Comment: Added related models to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try a performance test on this query? As you haven't posted your models, please adapt any field names.

The idea is to break it into two: one that will return all Article ids looking at the intermediary table.

```
queryset = Article.objects \
    .published() \
    .filter(id__in=Article.sections.through.objects
            .filter(section__full_slug__startswith=section.full_slug)
            .values_list('article_id', flat=True)) \
    .prefetch_related('lead_photo', 'authors') \
    .order_by('-published', '-id')
```

Comment: I added my models to the question. Your queryset took 76 ms. When I changed the order by to `.order_by('-id', '-published')`, which is what I need to maintain the correct order, the time went up to 1218 ms.

Comment: What was I thinking? In this way, you don't need the `distinct()`, because you are simple doing a `WHERE <field> IN (...)` and that doesn't duplicate results. Can you try now?

Comment: I couldn't get your exact queryset to work. I did try using the same approach though, by using `.filter(sections__id__in=Section.objects.filter(full_slug__startswith=section.full_slug))`. It was fast, but there where duplicates without the `.distinct()` queryset method.

Comment: You can't use `sections` in the filter otherwise they will surely duplicate. The trick is to select the article ids instead of section ids, and that can be done in the intermediary table (`through`). Can you tell what exactly failed in that way?